# Make Pong on android using OpenGL-ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to make a simple pong game using opengl-es. I have checked out some of the tutorials/samples, but most of them are pre-dated to 2009.

I am familiar with game programming, and consider pong to be the hello-world!

Right now, I intend to make it using their supplied SDK (2.3), but eventually I want to make it in NDK, so I can port my other work to android.

Would anyone have a good reference for a starting point ?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder why this got voted down ?

Comment: Possibly because it looks like homework.

Comment: Related: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/171/how-to-make-an-entire-game-x-off-topic

Comment: It doesn't look like homework to me, but still a terrible "question" anyway.

Comment: Its not homework. I know how to make pong and have made more complex games than that. I was having a hard time trying to find something which uses the latest sdk/ndk to establish the same framework as a game, which is why I asked for some references!

Comment: In this question's current state, I feel it would fall under 'how do I make game X'. And if you've made more complex games, couldn't you simply pick up an up-to-date API reference and write a framework? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already familiar with game programming, I would suggest you to get started with studying some source code. Here you can find an Pong for Android with source-code:
http://code.google.com/p/android-pong/

If you would prefer something like an tutorial, here you go: http://mikeyhogarth.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/how-to-develop-pong-for-android/

And further I would also recommend you the Android Reference to get started: http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

If you try it and get lost somewhere, you can come back here with more precise questions...

Comment: Doesn't using the NDK imply C/C++?  Your examples are all Java.

Comment: >eventually I want to make it in NDK

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single feature your game requires that would necessitate the need for the Android SDK 2.3 (Ginger bread). For instance, the improvements to the phone camera(s) in the 2.3 sdk will do nothing to improve your game of Pong whatsoever.

Do your game with Android SDK 1.6. Test it out with a 2.3 emulator, and you'll see that it works just fine on anything 1.6 and above. If you're doing this game to learn OpenGL (which frankly, your simple 2D game doesn't really need either), then you can use OpenGL ES 1.1 within Android 1.6, or if you'd prefer to learn OpenGL ES 2.0 instead, then target Android 2.1.

My point is: either do 1.6 or 2.1, they will both work as intended on phones and emulators of higher versions, but do not do it on 2.3, there is not only no reason to do so, and the syntax isn't even different, but that needless move would only ensure that your program couldn't run on anything, but  the Nexus S (the only phone that runs Ginger bread right now).